# Xcode bigobj option

Tags: xcode, clang

hi XCode 5 failed to compile file in 32-bit due to the size of the object file.
I tried to add -Bigobj flag but it doe not change anything.
I tried to change optimization settings without success.

the error is : "fatal error: error in backend: Section too large, can't encode r_address (0x1001a97) into 24 bits of scattered relocation entry."

There is no problems when compiling in 64-bit.

Does anyone have an idea about it ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "failed to compile file in 32 "?

Comment: Hi, i mean in 32-bit. i have no problem with the 64 bit version.